# Innodb mysql 5.7 cluster wont join after reboot

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-innodb-cluster

I get the following when I try to recover the cluster from a complete outage. Can anyone advise what's going on

> cluster = dba.rebootClusterFromCompleteOutage()
>
> Dba.rebootClusterFromCompleteOutage: Invalid value for localAddress,
> string value cannot be empty. (ArgumentError)

Thanks

Comment: Fixed it by adding "group_replication_local_address" value in my.cnf cluster config file.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding "group_replication_local_address" value in my.cnf cluster config file.